# I am getting some error installing Lombok on my system

Tags: lombok

I am installing a lombok and it can't write to my spring tool suite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J35sh.png)

Comment: Please post the error message you are getting as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: And did you try what the error message says?